# Matriz Quadrada em Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz

Meu código está imprimindo espaços no inicio e fim da linha, e está dando erro de apresentação (questão 1557 do URI) Alguém tem uma boa dica?
"Os valores das matrizes devem ser formatados em um campo de tamanho T justificados à direita e separados por espaço"

```
matriz = []

while True:

tamanho = int(input())

valor = 1

if tamanho == 0:

break

for i in range(tamanho):
linha = []
for j in range(tamanho):
  linha.append(valor)
  valor = valor*2
  if len(linha)==tamanho:

    valor = linha[0]

    valor = valor*2

matriz.append(linha)

tamanho_caracter=(str(matriz[-1][-1]))

tamanho_caracter=len(tamanho_caracter)

aux=tamanho_caracter+1

for a in matriz:

for b in a:

  convert1=str(b)

  print("{}".format(convert1).rjust(aux),end="".strip())

print()

print()  

matriz = []
```

Comment: Por favor, corrija a indentação do código.

Comment: Por favor, coloque a descrição completa do problema.

Comment: @MasterZub Comece por confirmar se a indentação no código da pergunta coincide com a que veio do seu arquivo, e caso não seja, ajuste a indentação aqui na pergunta para que fique exatamente igual à que tem. Lembre-se que em Python a indentação é vital, e sem saber como tem a sua é dificil de ajudar

Comment: @PabloAlmeida, aqui estar a descrição do problema:
https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1557

Answer (score 3):

O método `rjust` só existe para justamente inserir espaços no início  de uma linha. E você está chamando o "strip", que remove espaços numa string vazia, passada para o "end", o que não faz nada.

Leia a documentação da função print do python, veja o que são o "sep" e "end", experimente no modo interativo: você vai entender melhor do que se eu escrever aqui. E tenha em mente que em Python, identação não é enfeite: o código acima não só é sintaticamente inválido, como não daria pra saber o que voce queria fazer aí, se a gente nao soubesse que é imprimir uma matriz.

Answer (score 1):

Esta questão se refere ao problema de número **1557**, do site **Uri Online Judge** da categoria **Iniciantes**.

[Veja aqui](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1557) a íntegra do enunciado.

Como é possível perceber o primeiro parágrafo do enunciado diz: *Escreva um algoritmo que leia um inteiro N (0 ≤ N ≤ 15), correspondente a ordem de uma matriz M de inteiros, e construa a matriz de acordo com o exemplo abaixo.*

O exemplo - do qual a questão se refere - é formado por matrize `quadrada`, onde cada linha é formada por progressões geométricas crescente de razão `2`, tal qual exibido no referido exemplo.

Para resolver esta questão poderemos utilizar o seguinte algoritmo:

```
n = 9999
while True:
    n = int(input())

    if n == 0:
        break

    m = list()

    # Matriz base com elemento "0"
    for i in range(n):
        m.append([])
        for j in range(n):
            m[i].append(0)

    # Inserindo os elementos pedidos
    m[0][0] = 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        if i >= 1:
            m[i][0] = m[i - 1][0] * 2

        for j in range(1, n):
            m[i][j] = m[i][j - 1] * 2

    # Exibindo a matriz formada
    T = len(str(m[n - 1][n - 1]))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            m[i][j] = str(m[i][j])
            while len(m[i][j]) < T:
                m[i][j] = ' ' + m[i][j]
        M = ' '.join(m[i])
        print(M)
    print()
```

Observe que o `primeiro aninhamento` de blocos `for` se responsabilizará pela criação de uma matriz base com elementos `"0"`.

Já o `segundo aninhamento` de blocos `for` se responsabilizará por montar a matriz com os devidos valores.

O `terceiro aninhamento` de blocos `for` fica responsável pela exibição da matriz em forma tabular.

Este código já foi **testado**, **submetido** e devidamente **aprovado** no site Uri.